# Screenshot of iPad detail view orientation wrong

Tags: ipad, screenshot, xcode5

I'm trying to capture a screenshot of the detail view in a landscape master/detail layout on iPad.
This is the code I've tried using.

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
CGRect rect = [self.view bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, YES, 0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[keyWindow.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *capturedScreen = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Two problems occur with this.
 - the screen capture orientation is incorrect. I get an image that is on it's side.
 - The width=703 & height=768 dimensions are reversed by the screen capture so I end up with some of the master view in the detail screen shot.
What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```
-(UIImage *)captureScreenForRect:(CGRect)frame
{       
    CALayer *layer;
    layer = self.view.layer;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    CGContextClipToRect (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),self.view.bounds);
    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *screenImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return screenImage;
}
```

pass your detail view frame rect for above method. hope this will help you

The "official" screenshot method is here:
(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1703/_index.html)

Comment: Brilliant! It works perfectly for both iPad & iPhone. However you don't need the parameter being passed (CGRect)frame. Minor niggle.

Comment: glad it helped you.......yes it is, but can use this method as a method common without duplicating the code if you want use it some where else, just need to pass the rect size you want......cheers buddy  ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you need this for a transition or for a graphical effect and your using iOS 7 - I suggest you don't actually create an image.
An image can be heavy to generate (for example on iPAd Retina 3rd Gen) and heavy on the memory.

Starting iOS 7 Apple gives you a much quicker Snapshot function on UIView (Which by the way is also the way they implement custom transitions in view controllers , blur effect etc) that is done much quicker then creating an actual image.

On a UIView you can perform:
`- (UIView *)snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:(BOOL)afterUpdates`

Or if you need the full view hierarchy for a blurred view:

`- (BOOL)drawViewHierarchyInRect:(CGRect)rect afterScreenUpdates:(BOOL)afterUpdates`